# Is it possible to get a list of added or deleted files from Subversion?

Tags: svn

I want to retrieve a list of the files that has been added or deleted from our Subversion repository over, for example, the last month.

I'd prefer to have the file names, and not just a count.

Is this possible from the Subversion command line, or would I need to use a script to trawl the log?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with just the command-line tools, but outputting it with an XML format and doing some grepping or filtering would probably give you what you want.

Try this for a start:

```
svn log -v --xml | grep 'action="[A|D]"'
```

Comment: And if it doesn't work, this will show everything: `svn log -vr1:HEAD`

Answer (score 3):

I use the following lines to create 2 files with lists of added and deleted files. It's very useful for updating Visual Studio projects, when it's not the main dev environment.

```
svn diff -r 14311:HEAD --summarize | findstr "^A" > AddedFiles.txt
svn diff -r 14311:HEAD --summarize | findstr "^D" > DeletedFiles.txt
```

In the example it finds all differences between revision 14311 and HEAD.

Answer (score 2):

I use a mishmash of the SVN log command and grep to get just the deletions.
e.g.

```
% svn log -v -r \{2013-09-01\}:\{2013-10-31\}|grep '  D'
```

Will list the files deleted from the current branch in September-October, 2013 (Or... anything else with "space, space, dee" in it)